# Scribe with LinkedIn throw Response body is incorrect

Tags: android, scribe, linkedin-api

I use Scribe to connect to LinkedIn. But I get this error, when try to connect:

```
org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'oauth_problem=Scope%20NOT_AUTHORIZED%20%3A%20r_fullprofile'
```

I use this code for get RequestToken

```
authService = new ServiceBuilder().provider(LinkedInApi.class).apiKey(LINKEDIN_APP_ID).apiSecret(LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET).callback
            (LINKEDIN_CALLBACK).build();
new RequestTokenTask().execute();

//some code

class RequestTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            requestToken = authService.getRequestToken(); //error here
            authURL = authService.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webView.loadUrl(authService.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
    }

}
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Update:
I can't see in setting "r_fullprofile" permission. What I doing wrong?
[image: LinkedIn]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

permission "r_fullprofile" is deprecated.

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

Answer (score -1):

I would double check your LinkedIn Application on the Linkedin Developer page, To make sure you have the _fullprofile permission checked. As by the body its reading out that would seam to be your problem.

Edit: Also Make sure to check this , as it could help you with your issues
https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes